# increment a list in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, list-comprehension

i am reading a csv file,in return i am getting a set of url i have saved it to a list

```
urls.append(url)
```

then i am doing a while loop to parse through each url to get the html content of the each url

```
    i=len(urls)
    while(i<len(urls)):
        url1=urls[i]
        print url1
        mech1 = Browser()
        mech1.set_handle_robots(False)
        mech1.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
        page = mech1.open(url1)

        html = page.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
        ++i
```

when i have printed the url1 it is printing the first url many times,i would like to print each url from the list

Comment: `++i` does not do what you want in python

Comment: This isn't a list comprehension in any sense at all.

Answer (score 6):

I think the most pythonic way (and most clear, if that's not the same) would be

```
for url in urls:
    ...
```

So to be complete

```
for url1 in urls:
    mech1 = Browser()
    mech1.set_handle_robots(False)
    mech1.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
    page = mech1.open(url1)
    html = page.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `i+=1` instead of `++i`. Alternatively use the following:

```
for i in range(len(urls)):
    url1=urls[i]
    print url1
    mech1 = Browser()
    mech1.set_handle_robots(False)
    mech1.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
    page = mech1.open(url1)
    html = page.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

Or even better:

```
for url in urls:  
    # Add the code here
```

Comment: You shouldn't really give examples of things like iterating through `range(len(foo))` which are bad practice and non-Pythonic, even to show that there is a better way.

Comment: It's a matter of perspective I suppose.

Comment: That's not a matter of perspective, that's just bad code.